# Как сбросить input type=file, при нажатии на другую кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Вообщем я выбираю файл json при нажатии на кнопку 'Выбрать файл' и после жму на кнопку 'Загрузить', что бы добавить картинки на страницу из json файла(путь в json файл на картинке). Как мне после загрузки убрать этот файл из input type file. А то так получается, что я могу нажать еще несколько раз на загрузить и будет загружаться этот же файл. Нужно после первого клика как бы сбрасывать его? И вообще правильно ли я реализую это все?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery');
const buttonOpen = document.querySelector('.header__button-open');
const inputFile = document.querySelector('.header__input-file');
const buttonUpload = document.querySelector('.header__button-upload');
const fileBox = document.querySelector('.header__file-box');
let files = [];

const triggerInput = () => {
    inputFile.click();
}
const changeHandler = (event) => {
    if (!event.target.files.length) {
        return
    }
    files = Array.from(event.target.files);

    files.forEach(file => {
        fileBox.innerText = file.name;

        const addByFile = () => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsText(file);

            reader.onload = function () {

                const lines = reader.result;
                const linesObj = JSON.parse(lines);
                const allUrl = linesObj.galleryImages.map((image) => image.url)

                allUrl.map((url) => {
                    gallery.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
                <div class="preview">
                    <img src="${url}"/>
                </div>
                `)
                })
            }     
        }
        buttonUpload.addEventListener("click", addByFile)
    })
}

inputFile.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", triggerInput);
```

```css
.container {
    max-width: 560px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.preview {
    height: 20vh;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 5px;
}
.preview:last-child {
    flex-grow: 10;
}
.preview img {
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.header {
display: flex;
}
.header__input-file {
display: NONE;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header__wrapper">
                <input class="header__input-text" type="text" value="" placeholder="Введите url или выберите файл" />
                <input class="header__input-file" type="file" multiple="true" accept="application/json">
                <button class="header__button-open" type="button">Выбрать файл</button>
            </div>
            <input class="header__button-upload" type="button" value="Загрузить" />
        </header>
  
        <div class="header__file-box"></div>
  
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="preview">
                <img src="https://don16obqbay2c.cloudfront.net/frontend-test-task/images/493550740.jpg" alt="breakfast">
            </div>
            <div class="preview">
                <img src="https://don16obqbay2c.cloudfront.net/frontend-test-task/images/448964009.jpg" alt="building">
            </div>
            <div class="preview">
                <img src="https://don16obqbay2c.cloudfront.net/frontend-test-task/images/493550746.jpg" alt="cat">
            </div>
            <div class="preview">
                <img src="https://don16obqbay2c.cloudfront.net/frontend-test-task/images/448964007.jpg" alt="note">
            </div>
            <div class="preview">
                <img src="https://don16obqbay2c.cloudfront.net/frontend-test-task/images/493550739.jpg" alt="elephant">
            </div>
            <div class="preview"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов решения много.
Например, к каждому объекту изображения можно добавить флаг, что-то типа isLoaded = false, при загрузке отслеживать его, и при первой загрузке установить его в true.

Можно вообще объединить обе кнопки в одну - сразу и выбор файла и загрузка после выбора.